# Edup Wifi driver 8821cu won't work after reboot. I need to unplug and plug the Wifi back in

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, usb, network-manager

I am using Edup Wifi adapter model number AC1661 on `Ubuntu 20.04` with a kernel version `5.11.0.41` . I followed the instructions to download and install the driver from [this link](https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU). The driver works when I do a fresh physical plug in of the adapter. I am able to connect to the network. But once I restart the system. It won't connect to the network at all.

Here is the result of lsusb

```
blue@blue:~$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 14e1:3508 Dialogue Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:c820 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
blue@blue:~$
```

result of ifconfig

```
blue@blue:/etc/network$ ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:07:32:83:6c:fa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3729  bytes 265981 (265.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3729  bytes 265981 (265.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e8:4e:06:96:e3:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

result of lsmod

```
blue@blue:~$ lsmod | grep 8821cu
8821cu               2207744  0
cfg80211              888832  1 8821cu
blue@blue:~$
```

There are some duplicates for this issue but none of them provide an solution. Some of the tickets suggest changing the grub file. I did that

```
blue@blue:/etc/default$ sudo cat grub
[sudo] password for blue: 
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1 intel_idle.max_cstate=1 net.ifnames=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

I have also created a .link file

```
blue@blue:/etc/network$ cat 10-wlan0.link 
[Match]
MACAddress=e8:4e:06:96:e3:5f

[Link]
Name=wlan0
```

Here are the [logs](https://pastebin.com/SQCpVwJL) for networkManager when its not getting connected
And [logs](https://pastebin.com/wxzrG2kG) for when I am able to connect to wifi

Any Idea why this could be happening and how do I resolve this?

Comment: *none of them provide an solution* because there isn't one at OS/Software level. How peripherals are initialized depends mostly on the motherboard's firmware (UEFI or BIOS). You may try disabling Fast Boot and update UEFI/BIOS.

Comment: that would be a solution.  Update my UEFI/BIOS to do what?

Comment: The point is that isn't something related to Ubuntu or any other OS. Updating UEFI/BIOS is often needed even for brand new machines in order to improve compatibility, stability and the odd issues like hardware initialization. Please note I'm not saying it will fix whatever that is, just that it's something that should be applied if the manufacturer released some already.